# Optimized Paging and Sorting based on DateTime column having varchar type

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want optimized paging in sorting solution on my web application. For which I am using a stored procedure in SQL Server 2012.

I have used the following SQL statements in order to sort my column `CreatedTime` where I have saved date and time of orders.

However, that column's datatype is `VARCHAR` in the database.

I want to convert that column to `datetime` first and then sort based on that column. Apart from this I also want to sort based on `Profit` column and that column is also saved as `VARCHAR`.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
DECLARE @SortColumn VARCHAR(20),
        @SortDirection VARCHAR(20)

SET @SortColumn = 'CreatedTime'
SET @SortDirection = ' DESC'

SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER
      (
            ORDER BY  
            concat (CONVERT(DateTime, CreatedTime,101), ' ' , @SortDirection)

             CASE 
                WHEN @SortColumn ='CreatedTime' THEN concat (CONVERT(DateTime, CreatedTime,101), ' ' , @SortDirection)

                WHEN @SortColumn = 'Profit' THEN concat (CONVERT(DECIMAL(16,2), Profit), ' ' , @SortDirection)
            END


     ) AS RowNumber
      ,OrderID
,CreatedTime
,Profit
From Orders
```

The result of the above statement is not sorted based on the `CreatedTime` column.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is concatenating the **CreatedTime** column and **@SortDirection** variable so the following will be helpful to resolve your issue.

The following query is used as a sample table and data;

```
CREATE TABLE Orders (OrderID INT IDENTITY(1,1) ,CreatedTime VARCHAR(100),Profit VARCHAR(100) )
GO
INSERT INTO Orders VALUES('2020-02-19 12:10:57.083', '100.234')
INSERT INTO Orders VALUES('2020-02-17 12:11:17.973', '999.234')
INSERT INTO Orders VALUES('2020-02-25 12:11:48.277', '8892.234')
```

The following query will sort the column values according to the variable.

```
DECLARE @SortColumn VARCHAR(20),
        @SortDirection VARCHAR(20)

SET @SortColumn = 'CreatedTime'
SET @SortDirection = 'ASC'
IF @SortDirection= 'DESC'
BEGIN 
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER
      (
            ORDER BY  
          --  concat (CONVERT(DateTime, CreatedTime,101), ' ' , @SortDirection)

             CASE 
                WHEN @SortColumn ='CreatedTime' THEN CONVERT(DateTime, CreatedTime,101)

            END 
            DESC
            ,
              CASE  WHEN @SortColumn = 'Profit' THEN CONVERT(DECIMAL(16,2), Profit)
            END  DESC


     ) AS RowNumber
      ,OrderID
,CreatedTime
,Profit
From Orders
END


IF @SortDirection= 'ASC'
BEGIN 
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER
      (
            ORDER BY  
          --  concat (CONVERT(DateTime, CreatedTime,101), ' ' , @SortDirection)

             CASE 
                WHEN @SortColumn ='CreatedTime' THEN CONVERT(DateTime, CreatedTime,101)

            END 
            ASC
            ,
              CASE  WHEN @SortColumn = 'Profit' THEN CONVERT(DECIMAL(16,2), Profit)
            END  ASC


     ) AS RowNumber
      ,OrderID
,CreatedTime
,Profit
From Orders
END
```